# scp script runs perfectly under user but fails mysteriously under cron job

Tags: linux, security, cron, scp

I have a python script that performs an scp operation to transfer files from one Synology DiskStation (running Linux) to several Mac OSX computers on a local network. I have setup RSA private/public key pairs on all the machines involved. If I invoke this python script from the NAS drive as the admin user, then everything works exactly as expected. My NAS drive crontab file specifies the same admin user to run the script in the exact same manner. However, scp fails with an exit status code of 1.

What could cause this behavior?

**[update]**

Using scp -v (or scp -vv) reports more information. I can also see that it's supplying the correct key and the authentication is working as expected. Now I also notice that it has worked on a few of the OSX machines, but not all of them.

Comment: did you use the full path of your python script?

Comment: ssh interactively asking to add the remote host key? Incorrect permissions for private key file? Or missing PATH or PYTHONPATH component. Can you su and run the same script from the user's account?

Comment: ggioux: The ssh key is supplied directly to scp (via -i flag). I added the full path to scp (in python code) and the full path to the python script and the full path to the python program in the crontab file. I'm still seeing the same issue. However, I just started using verbose mode for scp. I'm trying to make sense of that now.

Comment: ggioux: BTW, I cannot use su or sudo on this distro of linux (for some reason) but the script does work as the admin user (same one the crontab specifies). So far that doesn't seem related.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that the .ssh/known_hosts and .ssh/authorized_keys were all in place for admin, but not for root. For some reason, when the python script was run under the crontab, the .ssh/known_hosts that was checked was the root known_hosts instead of the admin user known_hosts. So this challenge was brought up during the scp command and because it wasn't tty, it just checked the root known_hosts file, didn't find the remote host and failed. After adding all the OSX remote hosts to the known_hosts file, it worked smoothly.

I think an alternate (and more secure) solution could have been to install a separate crontab under the admin user, but what I did was just faster.